# Flatlander Vision

Tags: geometry

I don't think this is the right area *shrugs*

We have all seen (and drawn) a cube projected in 2D. Many of us have seen a tesseract projected in 3D projected in 2D.

Flatlanders are the same as us, but a dimension down. We see in a 2D space, flatlanders see in a 1D space. If a flatlander saw a square, how would he differentiate it from, say, a hexagon.

Comment: Go to the source. The text of *Flatland* ([available here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~banchoff/Flatland/)) includes a section called "Of Recognition by Sight".

Answer (score 0):

You can tell an edge-turned cube from a hexagon, can't you? In the same way, flatlanders can tell, even if they only had one eye, because of the change in light.
In a similar fashion, flatlanders can move left or right for context, extrapolating the shape and distance from the change. This is why we have two eyes, and why it would be beneficial to have two eyes as a flatlander.
Perhaps a flatlander can use echolocation to get an idea of their surroundings, although that would likely only develop if they live in the dark.